# Show Bootstrap popover in Code igniter

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i am using this tooltip popover from [here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers) .. what i want is to display data in this tooltip after getting the data from controller .. i dont know how can i do this .. i have a textbox where i have applied a blur function so if user enter something in inputbox it displays the data against it in tooltip .. i dont know how can i used this tooltip in my script

my textbox in view page

```
        Bill No:<?php echo form_input($bill_no); ?>
   <input type="hidden" class="hiddenUrl">
```

in this span i want to display the tooltip just infront or above the inputbox

```
     <span class="text">  </span>
```

my javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#bill_no').blur(function(){

            if( $('#bill_no').val().length >= 3 )
                {
                  var bill_no = $('#bill_no').val();
                  getResult(bill_no); 
                }
            return false;
        })
        function getResult(billno){
            var baseurl = $('.hiddenUrl').val();
          //  $('.checkUser').addClass('preloader');
            $.ajax({
                url : baseurl + 'returnFromCustomer_Controller/checkBillNo/' +     billno,
                cache : false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success : function(response){
                     $(".text").html(response.result);
                }
            })
        }
    })


  </script>
```

mycontroller...

```
       function checkBillNo($billno)
  {
$this->load->model('returnModel');

$query = $this->returnModel->checkBillNo($billno);

$billno =   $this->uri->segment(3);
$billno_results  = $this->returnModel->sale($billno);

//header('Content-Type: application/x-json; charset=utf-8');
echo    json_encode($billno_results);
```

}

Comment: What is not working? Clearify your problem. Maybe keyup() works better than blur() ?

Comment: i want to use the tooltip .. i want to display the data in tooltip ..http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips            this is what i am using ..

Comment: my code is working fine .. i just want to display the data in tooltip which didnt work if i do this.  <span class="text"  data-trigger="manual" data-title="This is a title" data-content=""></span>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to insert the returned text into the `data-content` attribute:

```
    function getResult(billno){
        var baseurl = $('.hiddenUrl').val();
        //$('.checkUser').addClass('preloader');
        $.ajax({
            url : baseurl + 'returnFromCustomer_Controller/checkBillNo/' +     billno,
            cache : false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success : function(response){
                 $("#bill_no").attr("data-content", response.result);
            }
        })
    }
```

or

```
$('#bill_no').popover({html: response.text})
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `$.attr()` to set attribute value like this:

```
success : function(response){
                     $(".text").attr('data-title', response.result);
                }
```